# php variable from variable

Tags: php

I have a variable and I want to create a variable with that. I get the variable from database and put it together with some text and then I want another variable.

For exampel

```
$a = $ . "txt" . $d;
```

Comment: That's nice. How about asking a question though?

Comment: (1) you should NEVER need this. It destroys all discoverability for other developers, (2) just use an array (3) `$a = ${'txt'.$d};`

Comment: PHP calls those "variable variables" [Here are the relevant docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: to Wrikken. it is because i get the the stuff from the database and then i need to relate to another variable with that one.

Comment: @Anders Wrikken is right. The only reason you should use variable variables would be if the variable already had been defined e.g. `$txt_3 = "Hello World!"` and then you need to call the variable like so: `echo ${"txt_".$row['field']}` assuming that `$row['field'] == 3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this. It will create a variable from another one.

`$a = ${'txt'.$d}`

P.s. This is a question asked a couple of times. You might have found the answer simply by searching the issue on google.

Comment: Variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php