# Variable in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know how can I get a variable which the combination of a character string and another variable.

Example:

$var1
ch1
and i want the name of the final variable like below
$ch1var1

id;  echo $nbr$id; ?>

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP manual for some quick examples. http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Potential duplicate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230957/php-variable-from-variable

Answer (score 5):

```
    $var1 = "Hello";
    $nbr = "var";
    $id = 1;
    echo ${$nbr.$id};
```

[DEMO VIEW](https://3v4l.org/o7oYp)

Use var concatenation

Comment: is ${} syntax new? never seen it before.

Comment: It is a way to use variable variables. Makes the code more readable. Here is a nice link with more discussion about the practice: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: yeah i know but has it always been around?

Comment: It's certainly been around throughout the life of PHP5, don't recall if it existed in PHP4

Comment: The syntax existed at least as early as PHP4.2 - http://techdoc.kvindesland.no/devcenter/php4.2/language.variables.variable.html

Comment: @MarkBaker: I seem to recall this syntax being used in a PHP4 environment, too: it's always been the way to avoid ambiguous statements like `echo "$some['array']";` or `echo "{$some['array']}";`, same goes for object methods, and properties of course

Comment: Back as far as PHP3 - http://techdoc.kvindesland.no/devcenter/php3/variables.html - can only find $$a format in PHP2

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${$some . $combination . $of . $variables . "or" . "strings"};
```

Comment: Could you explain why you use the `${}` ?

Comment: @stigok: Please see my comment on Sam's answer. In short it is just a more readable way to use variable variables in PHP. My comment on Sam's answer includes a link to an article that discusses the use of it.

Comment: @stigok it is a feature of the language.